# ASP.NET put HTML in Resource File using XML element

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, cdata

On my .aspx page, I have a value that I retrieve in my CultureDependent.resx-file.

my XML element looks like:

```
  <data name="BannerTextMain" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Test String, 
    <![CDATA[<html><body>
    <a href="/vacatures">link!</a></body></html>
    ]]>
</value>
  </data>
```

The problem is, is that my href isn't working : literal text is shown.

I was wondering if this was normal?

If i leave the CDATA section out of it, my text isn't shown at all.

how can i include a href in my text?

Comment: Please show how you render the string content in the .aspx page. You may be doing a call to `Server.HtmlEncode()` somewhere down the line where you shouldn't do so.